# how to create a lib file which has global variables and these global variables should share it's information to another project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

Created project in visual studio 2008.Now we want to split the project into many library files(DLL) but the problem is we have global variables which are in separate globals.h file using this file we are accessing global variables across project using extern keyword which are declare in externals.h.

How to share these global variables information across different library files ???

```
globals.h   externs.h
int a=0;     extern int a;
int b=0;     extern int b;
...        ...
...        ...
```

NOTE:globals.h is included only once in project.

Comment: When you say "library", do you mean a *static* library or a *dynamic* library (e.g. a DLL)?

Comment: read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h90dkhs0(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "globals.h is included only once in project" ?

Comment: that global variables are defined only once in whole project @ Fei Jiang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach for global variables is the following:

```
globals.h
extern int a;
extern int b;

globals.c
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
```

Note that the actual definition of the variables are in a c (or cpp) file.

If your are exporting global variables from a dll additional steps has to be performed.

```
globals.h
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern MYDLL_API int a;
extern MYDLL_API int b;

globals.c
#include "globals.h"

MYDLL_API int a = 1;
MYDLL_API int b = 2;
```

You have to define MYDLL_EXPORTS when you build your dll. If you use it from other dll's or executables, it must be not defined.

The `__declspec(dllexport)` tells the linker: This symbol (variable, function, class) will be used by other dlls or applications.

The `__declspec(dllimport)` tells the compiler: This symbol isn't defined in this project, but in an other dll.

Comment: got error regarding static variable declared in class while converting to dll's....can you provide documentation or notes, link regarding library creation using visual studio 2008 on windows.

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491990/c-definition-of-dllimport-static-data-member can help you.