# c++ with qt definition of dllimport static member not allowed

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not that experienced in c++ and I'm encountering an error I cannot solve. I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 qt Extension.
I know that there are several topics about this error and I have read for example these questions:
[C++ definition of dllimport static data member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491990/c-definition-of-dllimport-static-data-member),
https://forum.qt.io/topic/117453/msvc-2019-dllimport-static-data-member-not-allowed, but nothing of that worked.

The code looks like this (it was given to me from another project and I adapted it for to my needs):

filewriter.h:

```
#ifndef KEITHLEY2651AABSTRACT_H
#define KEITHLEY2651AABSTRACT_H
#include "keithley2651A_global.h"
#include <QObject>
#include "keithley2651Adatapoint.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <QTimer>

class KEITHLEY2651A_EXPORT keithley2651Aabstract : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setCurrentSetpoint(double setpoint, double rate);
    virtual keithley2651ADataPoint k2651ALogik() = 0;
    virtual void openDevice() = 0;
    virtual bool isOpen() const = 0;

protected:
    virtual void setCurrentCore(double setpoint, double rate) = 0;
    virtual double getCurrentCore() = 0;
signals:
    void newCurrentSP(double setpoint);
    void newErrorPPMS(QString ppmsError);
};

#endif
```

filewriter.cpp:

```
#include "keithley2651Aabstract.h"

const double MAXCURRENT = 50;
const double MINCURRENT = 0;

void keithley2651Aabstract::setCurrentSetpoint(double setpoint, double rate)
{
    if (!isOpen())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (setpoint > MAXCURRENT)
    {
        setpoint = MAXCURRENT;
    }
    if (setpoint < MINCURRENT)
    {
        setpoint = MINCURRENT;
    }

    setCurrentCore(setpoint, rate);
    auto report = getCurrentCore();
    emit newCurrentSP(report);
}
```

and keithley2651A_global.h:

```
#ifndef KEITHLEY2651A_GLOBAL_H
#define KEITHLEY2651A_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(KEITHLEY2651A_LIBRARY)
#  define KEITHLEY2651A_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define KEITHLEY2651A_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif
```

the error now says

> 'keithley2651Aabstract::staticMetaObject': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Can anybody help me and explain to me why this error occurs?

Comment: So did you actually define `KEITHLEY2651A_LIBRARY` while you're building your lib? I would guess no.

Comment: I have "DEFINES += KEITHLEY2651A_LIBRARY" in my .pro-file, is that what you mean?

Comment: When this is true I would not expect the compiler error. Please show the compiler command line and the real error message. It is also worth a try adding a #error 1 inside the `#  define KEITHLEY2651A_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT` to see if the compiler really goes there.

Comment: The real eror message is
'
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2491 'keithleyDMM6500abstract::staticMetaObject': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed Jc_Messung C:\Users\Florian\Desktop\Jc_Messung\Release\moc\moc_keithleyDMM6500abstract.cpp 89 
`

Comment: The VS debugger output is
'1>C:\Users\Florian\Desktop\Jc_Messung\Release\moc\moc_keithleyDMM6500abstract.cpp(69,1): warning C4273: 'keithleyDMM6500abstract::qt_static_metacall': inconsistent dll linkage
1>C:\Users\Florian\Desktop\Jc_Messung\KeithleyDMM6500\keithleyDMM6500abstract.h(15,5): message : see previous definition of 'qt_static_metacall' (compiling source file Release\moc\moc_keithleyDMM6500abstract.cpp)
'
I should probably add that this file is part of a greater project with a lot of other files in different folders.